# При запуске виртуального устройства андроид в линукс возникает ошибка.

Tags: android, java, linux

С чем может быть связанно. Вот что выводит при запуске.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'one'
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  28
```

С андроид раньше не работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите hardware acceleration эмулятора. Как сообщает мануал:

> Caution: As of SDK Tools Revision 17,
> the graphics acceleration feature for
> the emulator is experimental; be alert
> for incompatibilities and errors when
> using this feature.